# In select2 : How do I make the initial / default select2 option blank in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, ui-select2, select2-rails

The title basically says it all.

I want the initial placeholder value to be blank.

currently. It loads my first friend. I want it to be blank with a placeholder.

```
 = form_tag(compare_path, method: 'get', remote: true, id: 'compare_form') do
          = select_tag "v_friend_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@v_friends, :id, :full_name, @comparison.v_friend.id), :class => "compare-search", :style => "width:100%; margin-left: 3px;"
```

in my JS, here's what I've tried so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.compare-search').prepend('<option/>').val(function(){return $('[selected]',this).val() ;});

    $(".compare-search").select2({
      placeholder: "Search to compare"
    });
  });
```

I attempted to initially prepend it with a blank option value, but it's still being overridden by the first item coming from the instance variable in the collection.

I don't have a ton of experience w/ ror , so I'm trying to keep  out of the controller if I can get away with it.

Comment: `select_tag()` accepts an `include_blank` option(http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag). Have you tried that?

Comment: I"m also toying with allowClear: true, it lets me clear it and shows the place holder then, but the initial selector is not clear.  I'm trying 'initSelection:' No luck yet, though.

Comment: the include_blank: true, seems to have the same effect as allowClear. It lets me clear the selected item, but no luck in having the initial selection clear / blank when the page loads.

Comment: 4th parameter of `options_from_collection_for_select` specifies default selection. Can you remove it?

Answer (score 0):

```
= select_tag "friend_id",  options_from_collection_for_select(@v_friends, :id, :full_name, @comparison.v_friend.id), { prompt: 'Select Person', :class => "compare-search", :style => "width:100%; margin-left: 3px;" }
```

Comment: I tried this. It's not working. However, it does give me the option to choose 'select person'.

Comment: It's working properly with erb. Paste here what exactly you are writing

Comment: this is kind of working, but the issue now is that it messes up selecting the other options from the friends collection.

Comment: I am not getting it that what is your current issue?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this code:

```
<%= select_tag "friend_id", "<option value=\"\">Search to compare</option>"+options_from_collection_for_select(@v_friends, :id, :full_name, @comparison.v_friend.id) %>
```

Adding this:

```
"<option value=\"\">Search to compare</option>"+
```